# Scanner with input and delimiter

Tags: java, coding-style, java.util.scanner

I would like to create a `Scanner` with a `String`, and I was just wondering if there's a constructor / static factory method to do this in one line.

So far the only way I found is this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString);
sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\D"));
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I just realized I don't need to build a `Pattern`, `sc.useDelimiter("\\D")` works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it in a single line:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputString).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\D"));
```

[`useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) returns this Scanner so you can use it to chain invocation.

If you find yourself doing this often, you can build your own static factory for this, and reuse it.